# Java String Parsing and Evaluating

Tags: java, string, parsing

All,

I am in the process or rewriting some code that I wrote a while back.  The objective of the code was to calcualte a date and time based on a string in the following formats:

- DayStart+2Hour+1Day-2Minutes
- NOW+20Day
- MonthStart+1Month

Which would take the start of the day (in local time), e.g. 2011-09-15 00:00:00 BST (2011-09-15 23:00 GMT) then add 2 hours, add 1 day, and subtract 2 minutes.

The implementation is in Java and the original algorithm was pretty basic.  It iterated through each character in the string and appended to a buffer.  The buffer was then checked to see if it ended with the strings I was looking (date specifier e.g MINUTE, HOUR, DAYSTART, etc.) for then extracted the number and added to an ArrayList where DateOffset was a simple class with a int and String which was date specifier.  Here is some sample code:

```
// hard coded for sample
String s = "DayStart+2Hour+1Day-2Minutes";

StringBuilder sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();
String buffer;

// iterate through date string
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    sbBuffer.append(c);
    buffer = sbBuffer.toString();

    // check to see the end of the buffer string is what we expect
    if (buffer.endsWith("DAYSTART")) {
        offsets.add(new DateOffset(0, "DAYSTART"));
        sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    } else if (buffer.endsWith("DAY") && buffer.length() > 3) {
        String numberStringPart = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 3);
        numberStringPart = numberStringPart.replaceAll("[+]", "").trim();  // need as parseInt does not like the +.

        offsets.add(new DateOffset(Integer.parseInt(numberStringPart), "DAY"));
        sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    } ... and so on ...
    else {
    }
}
```

After the string was parsed I iterated through ArrayList to calculate my datetime.

The problem with the above is probably not efficient although we have experienced no problems.  It also does not pick up any errors so you could enter DayStart+2GKGKER.

I'm just trying to come up with some fresh and neat ideas on what to use to rewrite it.  I have done a little regex but not too sure if this would be the best route.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: What is with the weird data format? Can't you shimmy in `java.util.Date` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo, that was fun! Thank you! :-)

```
public class DateExpressions {
    private Map<String, Date> dateVariables;
    private Map<String, Integer> temporalUnits;
    private Map<Character, Integer> temporalOperations;

    public static DateExpressions createInstance() {
        DateExpressions de = new DateExpressions();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        de.setVariable("NOW", c.getTime());

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        de.setVariable("DayStart", c.getTime());

        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        de.setVariable("MonthStart", c.getTime());

        return de;
    }

    public DateExpressions() {
        this.dateVariables = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        this.temporalUnits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.temporalUnits.put("Second", Calendar.SECOND);
        this.temporalUnits.put("Minute", Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.temporalUnits.put("Hour", Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.temporalUnits.put("Day", Calendar.DATE);
        this.temporalUnits.put("Month", Calendar.MONTH);
        this.temporalUnits.put("Year", Calendar.YEAR);

        this.temporalOperations = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        this.temporalOperations.put('+', 1);
        this.temporalOperations.put('-', -1);
    }

    public void setVariable(String key, Date value) {
        this.dateVariables.put(key, value);
    }

    public Date parseExpression(String expr) throws IOException {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(expr);
        String s;
        int n;
        char c;

        int offset;
        int unit;
        int op = 1;

        Calendar base = null;
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        while ((n = sr.read()) != -1) {
            c = (char) n;

            if (base == null && temporalOperations.containsKey(c)) {
                s = sb2.toString();
                if (!dateVariables.containsKey(s)) {
                    throw new IOException("Unknown variable '" + s + "' used");
                }

                base = Calendar.getInstance();
                base.setTime(dateVariables.get(sb2.toString()));
                op = temporalOperations.get(c);

                sb1.setLength(0);
                sb2.setLength(0);
            } else if (temporalOperations.containsKey(c)) {
                if (!temporalUnits.containsKey(sb2.toString())) {
                    throw new IOException(
                            "Parse error: unknown temporal unit used '"
                                    + sb2.toString() + "'");
                }

                offset = Integer.parseInt(sb1.toString());
                unit = temporalUnits.get(sb2.toString());

                base.add(unit, op * offset);

                op = temporalOperations.get(c);
                sb1.setLength(0);
                sb2.setLength(0);
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                sb1.append(c);
            } else {
                sb2.append(c);
            }
        }

        if (!temporalUnits.containsKey(sb2.toString())) {
            throw new IOException("Parse error: unknown temporal unit used '"
                    + sb2.toString() + "'");
        }

        offset = Integer.parseInt(sb1.toString());
        unit = temporalUnits.get(sb2.toString());

        base.add(unit, op * offset);

        return base.getTime();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DateExpressions de = DateExpressions.createInstance();
        System.out.println(de.parseExpression("DayStart+2Hour+1Day-2Minute"));
        System.out.println(de.parseExpression("NOW+20Day"));
        System.out.println(de.parseExpression("MonthStart+1Month"));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for answer.  Nice and simple and much shorter than what I had.  I think this is along the lines of what I was looking for.  Nice and lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

Define a grammar for your expressions. Take a look at the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) framework to help you construct a grammar and process your expressions.

Comment: Thanks but looks a little overkill for what we want to do.

Comment: @Andez, defining a small grammar in ANTLR or JavaCC which include actions that do the actual calculations of your units will definitely result in a more readable solution than what you posted in your OP. Not overkill IMO. Granted, it takes some time to get acquainted with such tools, but it will result in a more flexible and maintainable solution.

Comment: @Bart - deffo one to look into for the future but as you should well know, us developers have limited time on our hands.  We always seem to be forced into modifying what exists rather than rewriting and introducing new technologies.  I got wrong for introducing XSL mid project before - though I'd implemented a number of solutions with it previously on different contracts - and it give us a completely flexible solution :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you're after rapid experimentation, sometimes a literate API combined with on the fly compilation is an easy way to go.

So, your example could look like (given appropriate static imports)

```
daystart().plus()
    .hours(2).plus()
    .days(1).minutes(2)
```

or even (given milliseconds as the basic units)

```
daystart() + hours(2) + days(1) - minutes(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems to be the best bet for such a scenario. Although, I'm puzzled why would you want to interpret strings in this manner, rather than having sophisticated APIs.

Comment: Saket - what you mean by sophisticated APIs?  We use this as we want to calculate a date offset from a given point in time.  Our configuration cannot use fixed points in time - for example we want to view data in effect between Day-5 and Day+5.  This seemed like a flexible way to do it.  This was a quick and dirty solution we came up with.  We are always open to better ideas.

Comment: I mean the stuff that you are looking to extract/parse our of the given string, why can't you define clear APIs for those? For instance `func(DayStart, Hours, Days, Minutes)` . yes, the string based approach provides flexibility, but also introduces complexities that you are trying to solve.